# How can I modify to fix this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm a new in iOS. 
I always use from JSON string to extract value data which I want. But, I faced that make a JSON string and send to web server. 
I have to make a JSON string this -> `"errorCode":"1491"`
and my code is below.

```
NSString *jsonRt = @"{ \"errorCode\":\"1491\"}";
NSLog(@"[D] jsonRt : %@", jsonRt);
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonRt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                      options:0 error:NULL];
NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);
NSError *error;
NSData *jsdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSLog(@"jsdata=%@", jsdata);

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsdata];
```

If build and run this code, my app is stop. I can't debug from breakpoint because suddenly jammed step over button. Where I fix this code?
I forgot the function return type. This is NSString*.

Comment: You create a JSON string, then you convert it to data, parse it. Then you encode it again to data. Then you get string description of the data which is something that is basically unusable. Why?

Comment: return @"{ \"errorCode\":\"1491\"}";

In general though, I sounds strange that you send an error code to the server...